# Using foreign keys and ContactsContract

Tags: android

I'm building an app where I need the user to select some "favorite" contacts and a phone number. I'm able to select a contact using

```
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, Contacts.CONTENT_URI), PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST);
```

and I'm able to extract all the information I need.

I then proceed to save the _id of the contact into my own database. My plan is to later list all the "favorited" contacts and display the name and phonenumber in a listview.

I want to save the contact id instead of the name and number so my listview will reflect any changes the user makes to his or her contacts.

But now I'm stuck. I don't know how to transform my table with contacts ids into a table with contact names.

I would like to something like this

```
my_table LEFT OUTER JOIN contacts_table ON (my_table.contact_id = contacts_table._id)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you will want to do here is to store those IDs then when you want to pull the names from the user's address book, you'll have to cross reference the IDs with the contacts intent you have store in order to filter them out.

Basically you cant join a non-existent table (contacts_table).

Comment: Guess my aproach with a database and a contentprovider is a bit overkill for what I'm trying to achive, but I wanted to do it to get a better understanding for how to use them...

Comment: Database is fine, the problem comes when you try to join a contentprovider on a database. This is not possible. You could create a helper class that would do this cross referencing for you, though.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably just save the contect IDs however you wish, and then loop through the contact IDs and look up the contacts one-by-one extracting the data you need. If that's quick enough you wouldn't need any SQL joins ("optimize by need").

Perhaps its even quicker to use some Google API and use HTTP/XML to fetch the contacts (perhaps cache them for a while as well).